# My <select> field will not show validation without the size being set to greater than 1

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 4 application. I have a `<select>` dropdown being populated by a javascript. I have tried a number of different ways to validate this field by adding a class="required", autofocus required, data-val="true" data-val-required="MSG" and NOTHING works unless I have the size set to something greater than 1. I only want 1 option displayed. How can I fix this?

Here is my dropdown:

```
<select id="lstBoards" name="lstBoards" style="width:450px;" size="1" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select at least one"></select>
```

Thank you in advance,
Chrys

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code, please?

Comment: There is no validation code shown. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the javascript code a little more, the developer added an Option to the dropdown list for a placeholder and gave it a value of 0, so the dropdown list always had a value selected, which means the validation was always working, it just wasn't failing because of the selected option.  To correct my issue, I changed the code from

```
lstBoards.options[0] = new Option("Select a Board", 0, false, false);
```

to

```
lstBoards.options[0] = new Option("Select a Board", "", false, false); //changing the value to null.
```

Thank you everyone for the replies,
Chrys